# Error:Class cast exception in elastic search while sorting buckets in aggregation

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, aggregation, classcastexception, buckets

> Error:
>                   ClassCastException[org.elasticsearch.search.    aggregations.support.ValuesSource$Bytes$WithOrdinals$FieldData cannot
>   be cast to
>   org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.support.ValuesSource$Numeric]}{[vTHdFzpuTEGMGR8MES_b9g]

My Query:

```
         GET _search
{
  "size" : 0,
  "query" : {
    "filtered" : {
      "query" : {
        "dis_max" : {
          "tie_breaker" : 0.7,
          "queries" : [ {
            "bool" : {
              "should" : [ {
                "match" : {
                  "post.body" : {
                    "query" : "check",
                    "type" : "boolean"
                  }
                }
              }, {
                "match" : {
                  "post.parentBody" : {
                    "query" : "check",
                    "type" : "boolean",
                    "boost" : 2.0
                  }
                }
              } ]
            }
          } ]
        }
        }
        }
        },
  "aggregations" : {
    "by_parent_id" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "post.parentId",
        "order" : {
          "max_score" : "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "max_score" : {
          "max" : {}
        },
        "top_post" : {
          "top_hits" : {
            "size" : 1
          }
          }
        }
    }
  }
```

I want to sort buckets by `max_score` rather than by `doc_count` which is the default behaviour of elastic search. 
I am trying to aggregate posts (which contains body and parentBody) 
by `parentId` and then sorting buckets by `max_score` and in each bucket
 I am getting `top_hits`. But I am getting the above error when I sorted 
the buckets by defining max score aggregation. Rest everything works if I remove `max_score` aggregation. Every post object has parentId, body and parentBody. I have used  the following references for coding this:

[Elasticsearch Aggregation: How to Sort Bucket Order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34195346/elasticsearch-aggregation-how-to-sort-bucket-order)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_field_collapse_example

Tell me what am I doing wrong? I have shared the query above.

Comment: please tell me how to java code your solution of max_score.Thanks

Comment: i was able to solve using "max":{"script":"_score"} this was missing